# Do photons change velocity instantaneously?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, photons

Any object traveling at c is observed as traveling at c in all reference frames. When a photon travels through a vacuum at c, all reference frames observe it traveling at c.

When a photon passes through a medium, it's speed is less than c. The moment that it begins to slow down, there is a reference frame in which the photon is stationary, as all reference frames at a speed of less than c (perceived in another reference frame) are equally possible and valid.

This would imply that if a photon were to change speed at all, in some reference frame, the photon is traveling at c, and then its velocity immediately goes to zero. Is this the case?

Comment: It is a very bad idea to look at photons like classical  particles, especially when you are investigating light-matter interaction. Photons don't slow down, and they don't have reference frames attached to them. The easiest mental model that has some chance of success in reality is that described by Feynman in his book about quantum electrodynamics "QED, the strange theory of light and matter". I would strongly suggest that you read it, before trying to reason your way in a semi-classical fashion around a sector of physics that is 100% quantum mechanics.

Comment: @CuriousOne - you are right, but this _is_ an interesting question. Restating: what happens to the apparent velocity of a photon in a refractive medium when an observer moves as fast or faster than the (lab frame) speed of light in that medium? It's not trivial...

Comment: @Floris: when something moves faster than the speed of light in a refractive medium, it creates Cherenkov and/or transition radiation, there is ionization, relativistic channeling etc... So unless we are talking about anything much beyond classical refraction (which is implied by the word photon), it's not a good idea to look at photons in media like classical particles... there is nothing classical about any of that.

Comment: @CuriousOne - I agree. But if I am moving at $c/n$ and look at light traveling through a block of glass with refractive index $n$, what do I see? Does the refractive index change with velocity (there is some density change happening because of length contraction and increase in mass); if so, is there a velocity for an observed at which the wave front appears stationary? If not, why not? And if so, what does it look like?

Comment: @Floris: That question, for classical waves, has a very important application in traveling wave accelerators: in order to "synchronize" the particles in the vacuum tube with the accelerating gradients of the em wave traveling in parallel, the cavity is shaped in such a way, that it has an effective refractive index>1. The em wave is moving at v<c, and the particles see basically a series of "standing" (or very slowly moving) electric field gradients. So, yes, one can travel "as fast" as an em wave, I would, however, not want to treat that in the photon picture.

Comment: @Floris: Here is an older paper with the theory of these structures: http://www.slac.stanford.edu/cgi-wrap/getdoc/slac-pub-3221.pdf

Comment: @CuriousOne - thanks for the link. I think I figured out what bothered me. The phase velocity of the wave is $\gt c$ but the group velocity is $\lt c$. Thus the observer traveling along at $c/n$ sees a series of ripples traveling along a stationary group...

Answer (score 1):

The "slowing" of light in a medium can be entirely explained using a classical wave-based approach.  An incoming EM wave wiggles the electron clouds around the atoms in the material.  These electrons clouds re-emit a much weaker EM wave having a very small amplitude.  This re-emitted wave is 90-degree phase shifted from the original wave but superposes with the original wave.  This results in a tiny backward phase shift in the net field of the wave at each atom.  After traversing many atoms, the original wave plus the superposed re-emitted waves yield a net wave that appears to be travelling slower in the medium.  Nothing is slowing down.

Another classical example:  Consider a long lightweight rope tied on one end to a heavy metal chain.  If you send a wave pulse down the rope, the speed of the pulse changes at the interface with the chain to a much slower (and narrower) wave pulse, but there is no deceleration taking place.

This is not to say that actual photons are waves in the classical sense, but they should NOT be thought of little bullets having mass which can be accelerated.  The interaction of photons with actual particles having mass does appear to take place *locally*, giving them the appearance of having a definitive position when detected, as if they were particles.